# indexx() Numerical Recipes (C) index sorting algorithm weirdly ignoring first two elements

Tags: c, sorting, indexing, numerical-recipes

I am trying to use the indexx() algorithm from Numerical Recipes (NR) in C and have found a very strange bug.

(NR is publicly available here: http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf page 338, section 8.4)

The function should output an array of indices that correspond to elements of the input array of floats, sorted from low to high.

Below is a minimal working example, showing that the algorithm appears to ignore the first two elements. The output array first two elements are always 0 followed by the length of the array (9 in this example). The remaining elements appear to be sorted correctly.

Oh and I tried to ask on the NR forums but have been waiting a long time for my account to be activated... Many thanks in advance!

[Edited array names]

```
#include "nr_c/nr.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    float unsorted[9] = {4., 5., 2., 6., 3., 8., 1., 9., 7.};
    long unsigned int sort[9];

    printf("Unsorted input array:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%.1f  ", unsorted[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    indexx(9, unsorted, sort);

    printf("Indexx output array:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%d    ", sort[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Should-be-sorted array:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%.1f  ", unsorted[sort[i]]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted input array:
4.0  5.0  2.0  6.0  3.0  8.0  1.0  9.0  7.0  

Indexx output array:
0    9    6    2    4    1    3    8    5    

Should-be-sorted array:
4.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: show how you wrote / copied that function?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Numerical recipes used 1-based indexing. (because of FORTRAN origin) As a result, **both** `0` and `9` are present in the index-array.

Comment: Show a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Names beginning with underscore and followed by another underscore or a capital letter are reserved 100% for use by 'the implementation'.  Do not use such names.  Names beginning with an underscore a generally reserved, though the wording is more complex.  Avoid leading underscores in names you invent; only use them in names provided by 'the implementation'.

Comment: @coderredoc I include the function with the NR nr.h header file. Unfortunately, the indexx.c function has several dependencies with other NR source and header files (afaik).

Comment: @joop Surely 0 and 9 cannot both exist? If the indexing begins with 0 then index 9 is the 10th element and does not exist. If the indexing begins with 1 then index 0 does not exist. Either way, the output would not correspond to the correctly-sorted input. (Note that the 0.0 that appears in the "should-be-sorted" array does not exist in the input array.)

Comment: @MichaelWalz As mentioned in my reply to coderredoc I have to include the full NR header file, the indexx() function has several dependencies, so I don't think I can do so easily. Of course all this code is publicly available but I understand that doesn't really help people verify this easily themselves. Please let me know if there's something else I can do to work around the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I've edited the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Numerical Recipes C code uses 1-based indexing. (because of its FORTRAN origin, the first version was written in FORTRAN, and fortran uses 1-based indexing for arrays and matrices. The C version was probably based on the output of `f2c` ...) 
In the original code in the question, the `indexx()` function ignores the first element of both the `unsorted[]` and  `sort[]` arrays. Plus: it accesses one beyond the arrays's last elements (resulting in UB)
As a result, both 0 and 9 are present in the index-array. (the initial `0` is in fact uninitialised memory, but it has not been touched by the `indexx()` function)

---

If my hypothesis is correct, the following should work:

---

```
#include "nr_c/nr.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    float unsorted[9] = {4., 5., 2., 6., 3., 8., 1., 9., 7.};
    long unsigned int sort[9];

    printf("Unsorted input array:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%.1f  ", unsorted[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    indexx(9, unsorted-1, sort-1); // <<-- HERE

    printf("Indexx output array:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%d    ", sort[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Should-be-sorted array:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%.1f  ", unsorted[sort[i]-1]); // <<-- AND HERE
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

The `numerical recipes in C` code assumes 1-based indexing: an N sized array has indexes `1..N`. This was done to not confuse the mathematicians. (as a result, a whole generation of programmers has been confused) The alloccation functions are wrappers around `malloc()`, which cheat by returning a pointer to the the `-1`th member of the allocated space. For a `float` vector this could be like:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

float * float_vector(unsigned size)
{
float * array;
array = calloc( size, sizeof *array);
if (!array) return NULL;
return array -1;
}
```

Comment: It does work, thank you so much! Can you explain why though, I understand the second edit is converting back from the fortran-style indexing, but what is the purpose and the effect of the -1s when calling indexx()?

Comment: As @joop said: NRC uses 1-based indexing. Their allocation functions (for Vector and Matrix) return a pointer **one item below** the actual `&array[0]`, such that indexing with `1` will get you the first element. so sad ...

Comment: @zooombini, "I understand the second edit is converting back from the fortran-style indexing" No. It still has same style.